Is egg-info still the recommended way to manage python packages installed in editable mode?
I am installing local python package in editable mode, using a pyproject.toml file to configure it. The pyproject.toml looks like this:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
dependencies = [
    "numpy==1.26.4",
    "pandas==2.2.3",
]
name = "pkg_name"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
dynamic = ["version"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = ["pytest"]


My install command is this: python -m pip install -e .
I noticed that this creates a .egg-info directory which contains the metadata for the package. My question is, is this still the recommended way to create python packages in editable mode despite the fact that .egg files have been deprecated, or is there a more modern alternative (perhaps more closely related to the .whl format) to an .egg-info directory which I should be using instead? If so, how should this be specified in the config for my package?

You do not ask for an .egg-info directory, only pip does... You are trying to handle responsabilities that belongs the maintainers of pip. That means that if (or when) pip is able to handle editable mode without eggs, you are too. My opinion is that this has not been seen as an urgent feature, but maybe a maintainer of pip could give you  a more detailed answer.
